# Custom table row in TableLayout of android app

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to create a table layout with custom table rows. Those rows should be like iPhone iBooks books shelf's like:

[image: image 1]

I believe the easiest way to do this is to create table layout with custom rows which would have image like one book shelf. This should be done in xml, i don't have many experience with this. Then by coding i would books images.

But i am new to programming android, so if there are easier way please tell me.

So maybe someone could give me tutorials or explain how to do this. 
For now i have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to use a GridView for this purpose? http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Comment: @Streetboy There is a project from Romain Guy(android engineer) that contains a similar layout, maybe you want to check it out: http://code.google.com/p/shelves/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

If there are limited data then you can use the TableLayout. and If you are using the TableView then the easiest way is you have to put the Image as background of table row.

Or

If there are many data then you can use ListView and for earch row of ListView you can set the background of that image.

Enjoy. :)

Keep Coading . . . .